# What is com.DesignScience.DSMTTool

Tags: launchd

Among my list of scheduled tasks is something called "com.DesignScience.DSMTTool" located at

```
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.DesignScience.DSMTTool
```

What is this? Do I need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DesignScience are the ones making MathType – an application used by Microsoft Word to be able to type out complex math formulas and display them easily. If you have Microsoft Word installed on your Mac, I think that's what it is. I can't confirm this though, as I don't have MathType installed.

Edit: I'm trying to get someone from [Mathematics](http://mathematics.stackexchange.com) to confirm it.
Edit 2: I was unable to get a confirmation for this, but I'm still pretty certain it belongs to MathType. Check in Word if you have MathType installed!

Comment: Sure enough, that's it! Some of these archaic (Windows legacy) apps leave a lot of junk around.